# how can I solve "msmq cannot be deleted"

Tags: c#, windows-7, msmq

[image]On my local machine,
I have a msmq that I cannot delete.

It says: `access is denied`.

How can I solve this?

Tried to change permissions and got the following error:

`WSecurity descriptor cannot be set`

Comment: have you added yourself to the security list with `Full Control`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have some more information about your problem? Screenshot or something? is it a computer at work or private? Are you admin on the local machine?

EDIT: More info in this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.msmq.deployment/wsmYc4yt6Ow

EDIT: Make sure you are in a security group that has Full Control

Comment: it has always worked, till i ran some script from NserviceBus site. Adding print screen